# .htaccess regex - "keyword" style redirects - syntax?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Problem: inbound outdated links to products that have been discontinued.
Challenge: many variations with additional keywords, subcategories, etc.

Examples:

- /somecategory/cool-widget-OLDNAME
- /special_sale_on_OLDNAME_items
- /category/subcat/subsubcat/morestuff/weird_keywords_OLDNAME

Needed solution: something that will catch the keyword "OLDNAME" *regardless of what it's surrounded by, and redirect to a specific page.

E.g. "RewriteRule **??????? OLDNAME ??????** http://www.example.com/newpage [L,NC,R=301]

The bold part is what I need help with.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Better yet, if there's a way to combine *multiple* keywords into 1 rule, that would be great. All of the requests for discontinued products are going to the SAME page (i.e. "www.example.com/discontinued").

Comment: JOUM - that's what I'm not getting... can you show me a couple of examples?

Comment: `^/.*(OLDNAME|ANOTHEROLDNAME).*$`

Comment: Didn't work.

`RewriteRule ^/.*(OLDNAME1|OLDNAME2).*$ http://www.example.com/discontinued [L,NC,R=301]`

What's my mistake?

Comment: may remove first `/`, cant test here, are normal rewrites working?

Comment: Yes, normal rewrites in the format `RewriteRule ^widgets/red-widgets/ http://www.example.com/red-widgets [R=301,L]` and regex rewrites (catching old keywords along with .php or .html) in the format `RewriteRule (^|[/-])KEYWORD-?(\d*)\.(?:html?|php)$ http://www.example.com/red-widget-KEYWORD$2 [L,NC,R=301]` are working fine. I'll try it without the leading "/".

Comment: Yes, removing the / worked. Thank you! If you can post that in the form of an answer, I'll mark it solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
RewriteRule  ^.*(OLDNAME|ANOTHEROLDNAME).*$ http://www.example.com/discontinued [L,NC,R=301]
```

it lookups any given word at any position in the given url.